# InstallUtil fails on installing custom Windows Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-services, installutil

I'm busy writing a custom Windows Services to handle MSMQ messages on a server, but the installation (using InstallUtil) keeps failing with the following error:

> "System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to get installer types in
>   the 'x'.exe assembly. The inner exception
>   System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException was thrown with the
>   following error message: Unable to load one or more of the requested
>   types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."

I am using 3 of my own assemblies in the service. All of them are set to 'Copy Local' and all other referenced assemblies are in the GAC. I have verified that all other referenced assemblies not in the GAC are in the the folder containing my services' .exe file.

I have also tried signing my assemblies (if that is worth anything...)

I have also looked around on Google, but in most cases the problem was either solved via a service pack, or installation of some proprietary software, which obviously solved the missing dependency issue.

I wrote a simple POC service, without referencing any 'outside' assemblies which worked fine...

I'm developing and testing on a Windows 7 machine.

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Ok weird... I was using PostSharp for exception handling and logging... I removed the references to PostSharp and my aspects, and it installed with no problem... o_O 
Is there any reason why something like PostSharp will not play well with Windows Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem... I applied the same PostSharp aspect twice to a method. So I had `Method1` and `Method2`, both have the `[MyException]` aspect applied. `Method1` calls `Method2` so the aspect is 'applied' twice, which didn't go down well with the Service Installer. I removed the aspect from `Method2` and all worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Without the installer, have you tried registering your service with all dependent assemblies? were you successfully able to register?
If this has worked, then -
Is your service registration action is post install complete action in your installation authoring steps?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry fo my english. I worked 2 days on this problem and i found that installutil works only if installutil and service and dependencies files in one directory.

installutil service -> works fine
installutil ServicePath\service -> dont work if dependencies in ServicePath directory.